# "Not In" returns no rows all the time

Tags: sql-server-2012, t-sql

Whats wrong with the following query. The first part of the **`select`** always return `0` rows.

```
 DECLARE 
    @AgentID varchar(20),
    @StringValues varchar(max),
    @ContactKey int,
    @Note varchar(255)


    SET @AgentID = 'c110010'
    SET @StringValues  = '08-328222,08-337333,09-348444,09-352555'
    SET @ContactKey = 0
    SET @Note = ''


     SELECT   @AgentID as agentid,mlsnum,'New' as status,ADDRESS,@Note as notes,PROPERTY_TYPE as propertytype FROM mls_unified_svo_tbl (nolock)
                    WHERE mlsnum IN (Select txt From [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@StringValues, ','))
                    AND mlsnum  NOT IN (select mlsnum from listing_cart (nolock) where agentid = @AgentID and contact_key = @ContactKey)


 UNION ALL
    SELECT   @AgentID,mlsnum,'Old',ADDRESS,'','' FROM mls_unified_svo_tbl (nolock)
                    WHERE mlsnum IN (Select txt From [dbo].[fn_ListToTable](@StringValues, ','))
                    AND mlsnum  IN (select mlsnum from listing_cart (nolock) where agentid = @AgentID and contact_key = @ContactKey)
```

Comment: Can the sub-select in the NOT IN list return NULL values?

Comment: Is `listing_cart.misnum` nullable? If so, use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`. Scratch that - always use `NOT EXISTS` and never use `NOT IN`. [See this blog post for a lot more detail](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join).